# SpecFlow Step Generation for Scenario Outline Generating Incorrect Methods

Tags: visual-studio, bdd, specflow, gherkin

I'm new in Visual Studio. I'm using Visual Studio 2015 with SpecFlow. Below is the Feature File:

```
@mytag
Scenario Outline: Successful Authentication
    Given I am a user of type <user>
    When I hit the application URL
    And I provide <email>
    And I click on Log In Button
    Then I will be landed to the Home Page
    And I will be able to see <name> on the Home Page

Examples: 
    | user      | email          | name  |
    | admin     | a.b@example.com | alpha |
    | non-admin | b.c@example.com | beta  |
```

When I generate the step definitions I'm expecting parameters in place of the variables, instead the method is generated as below:

```
[Given(@"I am a user of type admin")]
public void GivenIAmAUserOfTypeAdmin()
{
    ScenarioContext.Current.Pending();
}
```

I was instead expecting a method like:

```
[Given(@"I am a user of type '(.*)'")]
public void GivenIAmAUserOfType(string p0)
{
    ScenarioContext.Current.Pending();
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an example, surrounding the `<user>` in the `Given` step with `''` like this,

```
Given I am a user of type '<user>'
```

will generate the desired results. It's probably needed in order to recognize the regular expression.

[image]